# What is the largest possible value for a file descriptor in c?

Tags: buffer, file-descriptor

Is there a limit to how big the value of a file descriptor can be? I seem to have read somewhere that it was 1023, and just want to make sure this was correct.

Comment: Or would it be 32,767 since that is the max value for small integer?

Comment: Depends on the `ulimit` policy and the Un*x/Linux environment itself.